# How to prevent admob from working on background

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play

I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter)(admob_flutter) package to add Admob ads on my flutter app, recently I got a notification from google play that my app got removed and they send the following statement in my email:

> Ads associated with your app must not interfere with other apps, ads,
> or the operation of the device, including system or device buttons and
> ports. This includes overlays, companion functionality, and widgetized
> ad units. Ads must only be displayed within the app serving them.

After some research by that unclear confusing stressful email, I got that happened because the **Interstitial Ad** could still keep working if the app **not active** or be in the **foreground** or even after **closing the app** by the back button, not terminated.

So I have searched for how to listen to those events on flutter, and I did found the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` but I couldn't figure out how to implement it with my ad!!

Here's my code: ( didn't implement the widget tree in here as I guess not important )

```dart
AdmobInterstitial interstitialAd;
dynamic _state;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

  interstitialAd = AdmobInterstitial(
    adUnitId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
      if (event == AdmobAdEvent.loaded) interstitialAd.show();
      if (event == AdmobAdEvent.closed) interstitialAd.dispose();
      if (event == AdmobAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
        print("Error code: ${args['errorCode']}");
      }
    },
  );

  interstitialAd.load();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  interstitialAd.dispose();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);

  super.dispose();
}

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  setState(() {
    _state = state;
  });
  switch(state){
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      print('paused state');
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      print('resumed state');
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      print('inactive state');
      break;
      
    default:
      break; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the `interstitialAd` initialization code block with the following snippet:

```
interstitialAd = AdmobInterstitial(
    adUnitId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    listener: (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
        if (event == AdmobAdEvent.loaded) {
            If (_state != AppLifecycleState.paused) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            } 
        }
        if (event == AdmobAdEvent.closed) interstitialAd.dispose();
        if (event == AdmobAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
            print("Error code: ${args['errorCode']}");
         }
    },
);
```